# MySQL server eating all of my memory

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed MySQL 5.3 and I don't know why it's eating all of my resources. These are some screenshots of my memory usage.

[image]

[image]

What can I do to diagnose this problem?
My Server is having: Ram:2GB, RedHat5/Apache2/PHP5/Mysql5.1

Comment: This is _waay_ to broad; we can't answer your question without knowing _anything_ about your software or hardware setup.

Comment: Wait, you're *complaining* that the queries are being served from cache?? **Please** tell me I'm misunderstanding you....

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the [MySQL Tuning Primer script](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) (I think you need to edit some things in the top of the script first).

This is a very useful little script that will analyze your my.cnf configuration file and suggest changes etc.